# Thymeleaf , Map object which has value as List of districts .?

Tags: list, spring-boot, dictionary, thymeleaf

Suppose we have a Map object which has State as it's Key and List of districts in a State as it's Value. This how I am iterating over this kind of Map object.but each district is NOT getting printed on a new row. Can someone help ???

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(stateToDistrictMap)}">
   <table>
     <tr><td>State</td><td>Districts</td></tr>
 <th:block th:each="state : ${stateToDistrictMap}">
   <tr>
     <td th:text="${state.key}">State</td>
  <th:block th:each="district : ${state.value}">
    <td th:text="${district.name}">District</td>
    <td th:text="${district.code}">District</td>
    <td th:text="${district.erstyear}">District</td>
    <td th:text="${district.info}">District</td>
  </th:block>
   </tr>
 </th:block>
     </table>
</div>
```

Can someone help ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(stateToDistrictMap)}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>State</td>
            <td>Districts</td>
        </tr>

        <th:block th:each="state: ${stateToDistrictMap}">
          <tr th:each="district, i: ${state.value}">
            <td th:text="${i.first ? state.key : ' '}" />
            <td th:text="${district.name}" />
            <td th:text="${district.code}" />
            <td th:text="${district.erstyear}" />
            <td th:text="${district.info}" />
          </tr>
        </th:block>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: District object has fields like district name, district code, etc, how can we display that, can you please tell !!!

Comment: The required scenario,I have updated. please help  , <td th:text="${district.name}">Name</td> <td th:text="${district.code}">Code</td> <td th:text="${district.estyear}">Est Year</td>

Comment: #Metroids can you help ??

Comment: I edited my answer, I'm guessing that worked for you (because you accepted it)? Is there something else you needed?

Comment: ThanQ, It worked, right now figuring out CSS for the above template.